# How to adapt a regression demo from library Bayesian Optimization?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scikit-learn, regression, bayesian

I was adapting the next demo code to my own needs [The demo I used to "learn"](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/blob/master/examples/exploitation_vs_exploration.ipynb). I want to change the demo code in order to study the next simple model.

`def model(c,I,t):
    return I*np.exp(-c*t)`

I want to fit/adjust a GP regressor to the next target function:

`def my_target(t):
    return model(0.2,5,t)`

The ranges of variations of the parameters are given in the next dictionary:

`pbounds = {'c': (0, 0.4), 'I': (8, 10), 't':(0,10)}`

The gaussian process regression is instanciated in the next object

`bo = BayesianOptimization(model,pbounds,verbose=2,random_state=1)`

How does `bo` received information to fit to target???...

From the demo the gaussian process adjustments are done calling the method
`bo.maximize(init_points=0, n_iter=5, kappa=5)`.

Once again how did the function  was connected to my target????

I am trying to reproduce this example [my benchmark case](https://chaospy.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html) employing GPs....

Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite done. Question updated, thank you

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for the suggestion.  I have rephrase the question.

Comment: Much better. :-) Thank you.